# SQL insert using equality operator

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wanted to know if there is a way to write INSERT query in Key-Value pairs using equality operator. That way it would be more intuitive and more readable. I would just want to know if it is possible. And IF IT IS then how?

For example, instead of writing this way:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (column1, column2, column3, ..., columnX)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ..., valueX);
```

Is there something similar to writing it this way?

```
-- obviously this won't work. But is there something similar that does the job for insert
INSERT INTO MyTable
VALUES (
    column1 = value1,
    column2 = value1,
    column3 = value1,
    .
    .
    columnX = valueX
);
```

Thanks

Comment: what is wrong with the first example?

Comment: There is nothing wrong, but I think you missed my first line of question. "That way it would be more intuitive and more readable"

Comment: no the first is more readable, its saying insert into this table, in this column order

Comment: I think that's a point of opinion (which is off topic for SO). Using the `=` operator in SQL like that would be used to define an alias. So, for example `SELECT one = 1;` returns a column with the alias `one` with the value `1`.. When inserting into a column you, if you create a query that looks like it's using aliases, that could confuse people due to the same syntax meaning different things.

Comment: The syntax for `INSERT` is what it is. If you ask the designers, SQL is supposed to be more "natural" than procedural programming languages. Opinions on that may vary, but the fact is that you can't write an `INSERT` as if it was an `UPDATE`. No matter how badly you want to.

Comment: @JeroenMostert that's exactly what I was looking for, writing the `INSERT` query like we do with the `UPDATE` query

Comment: Per [the syntax](https://docs.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql), either you must specify all the columns in a column list, or you omit them but then you must supply all values for all columns in the order of the table definition. Given this, there is no workaround possible where you specify the columns in a list-like fashion. Even getting clever using `WITH` or subqueries or joins will not get around the basic fact that that column list needs to be there. Using `WITH`, you can get around the column order issue, but you will still end up duplicating the column list.

Comment: @JeroenMostert If you had written this as an answer with some examples and proper references. I might consider accepting it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only valid answer to the question posed is NO, you cannot do an insert like that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I will wait for a day or two before closing it, so that someone else may have a positive solution to it.

Comment: I hate to burst your bubble but there is no positive solution. This question comes up now and then. Syntactically it just doesn't work like an update statement.

Comment: I hate it when you are right but I was feeling optimistic. :P

Answer (score 1):

**Strong Caveat(courtesy -[Jeroen Mostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert)):**

> Be very, very careful with this, because all the columns must be supplied exactly in the order they were supplied in CREATE TABLE. The names associated with the columns in the SELECT will be completely ignored. Casually reading the code would suggest otherwise, and I wouldn't recommend doing this in production.

**My original answer:**

No, there isn't anything like that, but if you are inserting all columns except auto-generated ones, you can use following syntax with equality

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
SELECT 
    column1 = value1,
    column2 = value1,
    column3 = value1,
    .
    .
    columnX = valueX
```

Comment: Be very, very careful with this, because all the columns must be supplied exactly in the order they were supplied in `CREATE TABLE`. The names associated with the columns in the `SELECT` will be completely ignored. Casually reading the code would suggest otherwise, and I wouldn't recommend doing this in production.

Comment: If I can't change the order then there is no point in writing it like this.